# need solution postgres related tables indexes

Tags: postgresql, ddl

I am not god at all on pg database so that I place question here with my problem.

I have 5 tables:

- domains
- domain_check
- domain_registrant
- domain_registrar
- domain_tech

Now the structure of them:

domains:

domain_id|domain_name|init_check_id|last_check_id|updated_at|created_at

domain_check:

check_id|domain_id|check_status|updated_at|created_at

domain_registrant:

id|check_id|domain_id|name|updated_at|created_at

domain_registrar:

id|check_id|domain_id|details|updated_at|created_at

domains_tech:

id|check_id|domain_id|name|updated_at|created_at

Like you can see domain_check is related with domains and the rest tables are related with domains and domain_check.
What is the best way to create for them indexes and foreign keys ?

Can someone give me example of DDL ?

Comment: "What is the best way to create for them indexes" nobody can answer this. Indexes depend on the used query..

Answer (score 1):

An index would come with a primary key.  each of your tables should probably have a primary key. the domains table could be modified to have a primary key like this:

```
alter table domains add primary key (domain_id);
```

Then you could add a foreign key to the domain_check:

```
alter table domain_check add constraint fkdomains_domain_check
    foreign key (domain_id) references domains (domain_id);
```

This construct would put an index on the domains table and would add a foreign key reference to the domain_check table.